# Error template match invalid node (two xlmns)

Tags: xml

Please :
My xml is this(invalid) because the double xlmns in input node. Template match error...

XML Input (partial - second node in tree- the page don´t accep the original code :

```
<nfeProc versao="2.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
  <NFe xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">

  </NFe>
</nfeProc>
```

Thanks...

Elimar

Answer (score 0):

In general, XML tools will not accept input unless it is well-formed XML. Your input is not. To be pedantic, your input isn't XML.

The best approach to handling corrupt input is always to fix the program that created it. If you can't do that, you'll have to find some way of repairing it. If the problem is only in one file, then you can fix it simply "by hand". If it's a problem that affects many files, you'll have to devise some script e.g. in Perl.